# Flex 1 display issue creating Amazon clone app with Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, flexbox, display

I have a display issue with css properties "flex: 1;". I´m following a tutorial to make an Amazon clone app with Reactjs. The issue is in the header when the search input + search icon should stretch right covering all the possible space available between this search "div" and the other "div" with Links. Here is my Header.js code:

```
function Header() {
  return (
    <nav className="header">

      <Link to="/">
        <img className="header__logo"
          src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/amazon/amazon_PNG11.png"
          alt="amazon_logo" />
      </Link>

      <div className="header__search">
        <input type="text" className="header__searchInput" />
        <SearchIcon className="header__searchIcon" />
      </div>

      <div className="header__nav">
        <Link to="/login" className="header__link">
          <div className="header__option">
            <span className="header__optionLineOne">Hello Chris</span>
            <span className="header__optionLineTwo">Sign In</span>
          </div>
        </Link>

        <Link to="/" className="header__link">
          <div className="header__option">
            <span className="header__optionLineOne">Returns</span>
            <span className="header__optionLineTwo">& Orders</span>
          </div>
        </Link>

        <Link to="/" className="header__link">
          <div className="header__option">
            <span className="header__optionLineOne">Your</span>
            <span className="header__optionLineTwo">Prime</span>
          </div>
        </Link>

        <Link to="/checkout" className="header__link">
          <div className="header__optionBasket">
            <ShoppingBasketIcon />
            <span className="header__optionLineTwo header__basketCount">0</span>
          </div>
        </Link>
      </div>

    </nav>
  )
}

export default Header
```

My issue is regarding the div with className "header__search" including search input and search icon.

Here is my CSS properties for that:

```
.header {
  background-color: #131921;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}

.header__logo {
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 18px;
}

.header__search {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}
 
.header__searchInput {
   height: 12px;
   padding: 10px;
   border: none;
   width: 100%;
 }
 
.header__searchIcon {
   background-color: #cd9042;
   padding: 5px;
   height: 22px !important;
```

}[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BqVl.png)

When I change on ".header__search" display flex to display none it works, if I add flex: 1; to the search Icon ".header__searchIcon" it expands to the right covering all the available space. I don´t understand why the div can´t do it. I just do exaclty what they do on the tutorial but doesn´t have the same result.

Comment: If you don't have a link to reproducible code, could you show your full CSS? What styles are applied to the `.header__link` class?

Comment: .header__optionBasket {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.header__basketCount {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.header__nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.header__option {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.header__optionLineOne {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.header__optionLineTwo {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.header__link {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}